# Calculating automorphism groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I've been given a field $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and I have to find $Aut(\frac{L}{Q})$.

Now i know that $\sqrt[4]{2}$ has minimal polynomial $x^4 -2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence $[L : 
\mathbb{Q}] = 4$, so a $\mathbb{Q}$ basis for $L$ has 4 elements, with two of them being $1$ and $\sqrt[4]{2}$ but I cannot figure out other two.

In terms of finding the automorphisms $\sigma$, I know that if we let $\sigma \in$ $Aut(\frac{L}{Q})$ then $\sigma$ is determined by $\sigma(\sqrt[4]{2})$, and from here I am not quite sure how to calculate the group of automorphisms.

Comment: Hints: 1) A $K$-basis for $K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ with $f$ irreducible of degree $n$ consists of the powers $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1}$. In your case $f(x)=x^4-2$. 2) If $f(x)\in K[x]$, and $L$ is an extension field of $K$, then any $K$-automorphism of $L$ must map a root of $f(x)$ to another. What roots does $x^4-2$ have in your field $L$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to remember here is that **every automorphism sends an element to another root of its minimal polynomial.**

As you correctly observe, $\sigma$ is determined by where it sends $\sqrt[4]{2}$.  But it can only send $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to another root of its minimal polynomial, $x^4 - 2 = 0$.  The roots of this are $\pm \sqrt[4]{2}$ and $\pm i\sqrt[4]{2}$.  So there are four possible $\sigma$s.  Now rule out two of those possibilities by saying that this field is entirely contained in the real numbers.

Answer (score 5):

There are only two automorphisms, its not Galois. The nontrivial is 
$\sigma(\sqrt[4]{2})=-\sqrt[4]{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Ok a few things:

First, you are correct that $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 4$.  You can select any basis you want, so long as the elements you've chosen are linearly independent, so in particular, two of them don't *have* to be $1$ and $\sqrt[4]{2}$.  A simple way of doing this for a simple extension $F[a]/F$ of degree $n$ is to simply take powers of the adjoining element: $\{1, a, a^2, \cdots, a^{n-1}\}$ (why?).

Next, it is a theorem that $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = |\operatorname{Aut}(K/\mathbb{Q})|$   if and only if $K$ is a splitting field of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Otherwise, it is a theorem that the order of the automorphism group divides $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$.  (These are important results that you should be able to find in your textbook.)

Since $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$ is not a splitting field, then notice that this greatly restricts the possibilities for $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]/\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Shouldn't $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ be equal to 2?

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi, nope.  It is $4$, since $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is the root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: But $L=\{ a+b\sqrt[4]{2} | a,b\in\mathbb{Q} \}$ which clearly has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I think I'm going wrong somewhere!

Comment: @Swapnil: you also need the second and third power of the fourth root of two to generate $L$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  You should review the difference of a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of an extension and the field generators.  The first generates the extension as a vector space over the rationals, the second as an algebra over the rationals.  Try expressing the $\sqrt{2}$ as a linear combination of $1$ and the fourth root of two over $\mathbb{Q}$.  You cannot.

Comment: Yes. This makes sense now. Thank you.